# High dimensional optimization alternatives for optim()

Tags: r, mathematical-optimization, nonlinear-optimization

I have implemented a wrapper function for `optim` using a non-standard (piecewise linear) cost function and optimizing with regard to this cost function. (Think `lm` but with the cost function least squares replaced with a custom function.)

This process works very well for low-dimensional mock data. However, my data (which unfortunately I cannot share) is relatively high-dimensional (~100 columns, no constant columns).

Using this high-dimensional data, the optimization parameters differ from their initial values by ~0.001 (more or less depending on the method used), even using the argument `control = list(maxit = 5000)` and trying out all implemented optimization `method`s:

`optim(par = c(mean(b), rep(0, ncol(A) - 1)), fn = costFn, A = A, b = b, method = "CG", control = list(maxit = 5000))`
Here `A` is the matrix of predictors, `b` is the dependent variable and the `costFn` is defined as

```
costFn <- function(A, par, b) {
    sum(
      wPlus * pmax(A %*% par - b, 0)
      + wMinus * pmax(b - A %*% par, 0)
    )
  }
```

with constants `wPlus`, `wMinus` > 0.

I feel like this process terminates way too fast for 5000 iterations (< 2 seconds).

The cost function regarded as a function R->R is convex and the input is a linear combination of the predictors and the dependent variable so it should also be convex regarded as a function R^n->R. Therefore, the methods should converge to the global minimum (and not get stuck in local minima as there are no others). Correct me if I am wrong here.

My question is if I seem to have made an obvious mistake (which, I know, is hard to tell as I cannot provide a reprex) or if there are better alternatives to `optim`.

Possible mistakes include:

- The cost function is in fact not convex and so the algorithm does not converge to the global minimum.
- As the data is high-dimensional, many iterations may be needed. Perhaps I have not used the `maxit` argument correctly.
- The implemented methods are not suitable for high-dimensional data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is non-differentiable, so you can expect local, gradient-based NLP solvers to get into trouble. However, what you have is a slight generalization of the L1-norm or LAD regression:

```
 min sum(k, |r[k]|)
 r = Ax - b 
 r, x free variables
```

This is basically your problem with `wPlus=wMinus = 1`. This L1 problem can be stated as a Linear Programming (LP) model as follows:

```
min sum(k, rPlus[k] + rMin[k])
rPlus - rMin = Ax - b
rPlus[k],rMin[k]>=0
x free variable
```

LP solvers for use under R are readily available.

The modeling technique we used here is called **variable splitting**  [[link](https://yetanothermathprogrammingconsultant.blogspot.com/2017/11/lp-and-lad-regression.html)]. In the optimal solution only one of each pair `(rPlus[k],rMin[k])` will be non-zero.

We can use this formulation for **your problem** by just adjusting the objective a little bit:

```
min sum(k, wPlus*rPlus[k] + wMin*rMin[k])
rPlus - rMin = Ax - b
rPlus[k],rMin[k]>=0
x free variable
```

LP problems with many variables and many constraints can be solved very efficiently using a good LP solver.